# Is VistaDB compatible with Microsoft Enterprise Library DAAB?

Tags: .net, database, enterprise-library, embedded-database, vistadb

As the title asks, is VistaDB 3.x/4.x supported in Data Access Application Block (DAAB) of Microsoft Patterns and Practices Enterprise Library 3.x/4.x?

If it is and you have used the two together, are there any issues or caveats I should know about?  Or... Could anybody provide links to source code for the custom provider for Enterprise Library?

EDIT:

- Has anybody tried writing a custom provider for VistaDB 3.x/4.x in Enterprise Library 3.x/4.x with any success?